# React scroll to top not working when navigating backwards

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToTop({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    }
  }, []);

  return (null);
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```

Placed just above my switch

```
     <React.Fragment >
                           <ScrollToTop /> 
                            <Switch>
                              <Route
                                exact
                                path="/error"
                                render={() => (
                                  <Error
                                    {...this.props}
                                    scrollInfo={scrollInfo}
                                    params={params}
                                    paramsChange={this.updateUrl}
                                    sendError={true}
                                    showFooter={true}
                                    showHeader={true}
                                  ></Error>
                                )}
                              />
    
                              <Route
                                exact
                                path="/errorLookup"
                                render={() => (
...
```

It works fine, but when going back in a page apparently it doesnt work. (Being it the browser button, or an in app history.push)
What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

In react-router, when you press back, it will navigate the user to their exact last position and there is good inbuilt functionality provided by react-router but you can ignore it via handle back button.

```
function handleBackButtonClick() {
    // scroll top function
    return true;
}

useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonClick);
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Where is BackHandler coming from, I cant seem to detect it?
Also im using my scroll top function as a component (As seen above) so I dont really understand how to put it in a function.

Comment: BackHandler is coming from react native and you need to copy `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` this where I did comment